# Amcharts4 numberFormatter percentage doesn't work

Tags: amcharts4

Reading https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/formatters/formatting-numbers/, it seems to me that to display data as percentages you only need to write :

```
chart.numberFormatter.numberFormat = "%";
```

However, not only it doesn't work, but it also hides all data-related information. It seems to be a bug because other formats such as "#.##" work fine.

Here is a stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-1arbck

Any help  is appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the percentage value in chart, then calculate the percentage value at front/back end and the show the value in chart. Sometimes Amcharts percentage calculation will not match with your calculated percentage value. Also, use `chart.numberFormatter.numberFormat = "#.## '%'";` to show the percentage sign.

Comment: Your last sentence is what I was looking for, I would never have thought about using "%" after "#.##". Thank you very much

Comment: Yeah, just to add to this that it isn't a bug - `%` is a modifier for `#` so you need to pair them together (`#%`, `#.##%` will calculate as percent). Single quotes around the `%` will just show a percent sign instead of doing the conversion.